# How to work event listener in EVM?

Tags: solidity, events, evm

I didn't understand contract event listener works style. I guess, It doesn't work like to socket streaming. Because, When I am listening previous logs show to me too with new logs.

I wonder, is there a queuing process like Redis (or do Events  chaining too?) in triggering events in the Blockchain network? If is it, my project fiction I should change.

I would like to explain another situation I encountered with an example; I was listen ERC721 token standart's `Transfer` event from any project contract address at the mint day. I noticed tokenId (so value params) jump without arithmetic increment as 1030, 1031, ..., 1067, 1068.

```js
contract.on('Transfer', (from, to, value) => {
  console.log(from, to, parseInt(value._hex,16))
});
```

Can someone explain where I misunderstood?

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the contract code? perhaps the minting function doesn't require 'arithmetic' jump

Comment: @v1bio Hmm, you can check here; https://etherscan.io/address/0xAEbe0Cdbc3b0AE6ca0C632EBd8D1063dC36B7D2A#code